# OSAtmonicCompareAndSwap32 is giving me a warning that I can't figure out

Tags: ios, ios7, nsinteger

```
- (void)decrementActivityCount {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"activityCount"];
    bool success;
    do {
        int32_t currentCount = (int32_t)_activityCount;
        success = OSAtomicCompareAndSwap32(currentCount, MIN(currentCount - 1, currentCount), &_activityCount); 
        //Incompatible pointer types passing 'NSInteger *' (aka 'long *') to parameter of type 'volatile int32_t *' (aka 'volatile int *')
    } while(!success);
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"activityCount"];
    [self updateNetworkActivityIndicatorVisibilityDelayed];
}
```

_activityCount is an NSInteger

Above is my code and two issues.

1. What is the OSAtmonicCompareAndSwap32 actually doing?
2. How can I remove the warning?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the OSAtmonicCompareAndSwap32 actually doing?

It atomically compares *currentCount* and _*activityCount*, and if they are equal, it sets _*activityCount* to `MIN(currentCount - 1, currentCount)`.

It returns true if the comparison was equal.

So, basically it performs an atomic decrement by 1. The same can be accomplished with less code.

> How can I remove the warning?

_*activityCount* MUST be an `int32_t`, OR

use 64-bit integers and the 64-bit variants of CompareAndSwap:

`OSAtomicCompareAndSwap64`

Comment: the code is for iOS. So what do I need to do to make sure it works on 32-bit and 64-bit systems

Comment: Instead of defining _activityCount as a NSInteger, define either int32_t or int64_t and the corresponding functions.